# Cannot find hopf bifurcation numerically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Using [first Lyapunov coefficient](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Andronov-Hopf_bifurcation)
it can be shown that the system

> \begin{aligned} \left(\begin{array}{c} r'\\ \\ z'\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} \displaystyle \frac{3 k n^2 r \left(n^2 (-1+r^2)+4 m^2 (-1+z^2)\right)}{8 m^5} \\ \displaystyle -\frac{n (m^2+k n) z \left(3 n^2 (-1+r^2)+2 m^2 (-1+z^2)\right)}{2 m^5}\end{array}\right) \end{aligned}

has a Hopf bifurcation at the equilibrium point $(1,1)$ with the bifurcation parameter $$k=\frac{8 m^4 n}{-8 m^2 n^2 + 3 n^4} .$$ But I cannot find this periodic orbit when plotting the phase portrait of this system. Is it possible that this limit cycle is too small to be seen? Can you help me to plot this periodic solution? I can use MATHEMATICA, MACSIMA or Matlab.

Comment: The gold standard for numerical bifurcation software is AUTO 07p, which definitely has specialized routines for Hopf bifurcations. Unfortunately it has a bit of a learning curve to even get started.

Comment: By the way, please use MathJax to format your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion and formating @Ian

Comment: . The typical values are $m=1$  and $n=2$ @Moo.

Comment: After spending one hour trying to install AUTO 07p on windows. I just give up. I believe it is a good software but it is not practical at all.

Comment: Oh no, I would never try to use it on Windows. It's compatible but only technically.

Comment: Thank you very much @Moo. Since I analytically proved a Hopf bifurcation around $(1,1)$ I would do like to plot some numerical solution over this figure that you sent me. Showing that the solutions really spirals towards a limit cycle. Not to the equilibrium point or the homoclinic connection that we can see in your plot.

Answer (score 1):

With $m=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}$, $n=2$ and the critical bifurcation value $k=\displaystyle\frac{1}{16}$. For $k<\displaystyle\frac{1}{16}$ the equilibrium point $(1,1)$ is locally asymptotically stable, and for $k>\displaystyle\frac{1}{16}$ is locally asymptotically unstable. Use $k=\displaystyle\frac{1}{16}\pm \displaystyle\frac{1}{100000}$. Inititial condition $r(0)=z(0)=1\pm \displaystyle\frac{1}{1000} $.

Time series:

[image]

Phase portrait:

[image]

`Using Wolfram Mathematica`